# Uncrustify command for CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, code-formatting, uncrustify

I would like to apply `uncrustify` (via beautify in the Atom editor and a config file) to CUDA code. However, I don't know how to tell uncrustify to recognize CUDA kernel calls which have the following structure:

```
kernelName <<<N,M>>> (arg0,arg1,...);
```

However, uncrustify has problems with the `<<< >>>` and applying it gives the following unpleasant result

```
kernelName << < N, M >> >
    (arg0,arg1,...);
```

I would like to have it look more like a function call and also avoid the formatting of `<<<` to `<< <`. Ideally, the result would look like

```
kernelName <<< N, M >>> (arg0,arg1,
      ...); // line break if argument list is too long
```

Which arguments can I add to my `config.cfg` to achieve the above result?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking through whole documentation of uncrustify, I have found 2 arguments that could influence in your CUDA kernel style:

```
sp_compare                                { Ignore, Add, Remove, Force     }
 Add or remove space around compare operator '<', '>', '==', etc
```

And:

```
align_left_shift                          { False, True }
  Align lines that start with '<<' with previous '<<'. Default=true
```

You can try to play around with these parameters to be more closely to the solution although I would try something like:

```
sp_compare     =   Remove
align_left_shift   = False
```